# Run current line from vim in console (R, Matlab, Python, etc.) over SSH

Tags: r, matlab, vim, ssh, tmux

I often find myself using SSH to remote into a server, and using tmux to split the terminal into two panes: editor (vim) and the console for either R/Matlab/Python, depending on which language I am working with.  This way, I can perform some kind of analysis "interactively," and then use my mouse or tmux to copy the commands to my text editor so that I can make a script out of them.

This is quite inefficient, as I have to copy all the commands over to my text editor every time I run a command in the console.  If I were working locally, I would open the Matlab GUI/IDE or R Studio, where I can write my commands in a script, and then execute them immediately after writing it with a convenient shortcut (e.g. cmd + enter) that will run the current line.  This way, I can take advantage of the interactive terminal, while also building a script to replicate my work. But often I cannot do X forwarding, so the GUI IDEs are not available.

Is it possible to script vim and/or tmux to somehow run the current line from the editor in the open console session?

Please note that just saving and running the entire file is not a solution, because often the analysis takes significant amount of time, and I do not want to run everything from the beginning.

Comment: I achieved this by a combination of calling `tmux send-keys` from vim and sending the current line (which I get using a python vim script, but I guess there are other ways) to the pane where Matlab console  is running

Comment: Unfortunately, this question has been closed, but I will give my definitive answer as a comment.  I find that [Conque Shell](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2771) solves this problem beautifully.  I run :ConqueTermSplit python, or matlab -nodisplay, or R, and I have one pane for my script, and I can easily copy it over to the console to run it

Answer (score 0):

This is not the answer to the question, but just a suggestion with alternatives

1 - Install "RStudio Server" on the Server. Then you can use the GUI to maintain scripts and submit commands to the console.

2 - Use Notebook tools tools like Juypter with R kernel - https://github.com/IRkernel/IRkernel

Both allow code submission, script maintenance and graphics to be returned form the server to the webpage.

Answer (score 0):

One solution, although not very elegant, would be to write a vim script that saves a temporary file with just the current line and runs that file. It would go something like

```
:.w temp.m
:!matlab temp.m
```

to extend with filetype awareness and such to your hearts content.

Comment: The problem there is that you would be opening a new matlab session every time, correct?

Comment: I don't currently have Matlab installed on Linux anywhere close, so I cannot test it. But I am fairly certain that if the above doesn't already run matlab in the already active session, there is a command-line switch that will do it right.